# Quadratically constrained MIQP with julia and gurobi

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

This is an attempt to answer the following question:  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/small-data-sets-with-integral-sample-standard-deviations

So the intent of the following code is to find examples of small datasets with integer standard deviation. That can be formulated as a quadratically constrained mixed integer quadratic program, so I try to use Gurobin from Julia.  Following is my code:

```
using JuMP  
using Gurobi

m = Model(solver = GurobiSolver() )
@variable(m,  0<= x[1:20] <= 100,  Int)
@variable(m,  Gj,  Int)
@constraint(m,  Gj == sum(x[1:20])/20 )
@variable(m,  Var,  Int)
@constraint(m,  Var == sum( (x[1:20]-Gj).^2/19) )
@variable(m,  sd,  Int)
@constraint(m, sd * sd == Var)
### We need some restrictions to avoid all equal, < or zero,  solutions:
@constraint(m,  sd >= 5)
@objective(m, Min, sd)

print(m)

status = solve(m)

println("Objective value: ", getobjectivevalue(m) )

x = getvalue(x)
```

Running this results in:

```
ERROR: Gurobi.GurobiError(10021, "Quadratic equality constraints")
Stacktrace:
 [1] optimize(::Gurobi.Model) at /home/kjetil/.julia/v0.6/Gurobi/src/grb_solve.jl:7
 [2] optimize!(::Gurobi.GurobiMathProgModel) at /home/kjetil/.julia/v0.6/Gurobi/src/GurobiSolverInterface.jl:294
 [3] #solve#101(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::JuMP.Model) at /home/kjetil/.julia/v0.6/JuMP/src/solvers.jl:173
 [4] solve(::JuMP.Model) at /home/kjetil/.julia/v0.6/JuMP/src/solvers.jl:148
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A math programming solver like Gurobi Optimizer cannot solve models with quadratic equality constraints. [Here are the types of constraints that Gurobi Optimizer can solve](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/constraints.html).  To solve your model using Gurobi Optimizer, you must transform your constraints into one of these forms, such as quadratic inequality constraints.

Comment: I don't understand: From [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/the_model_argument.html), it seems this is possible, but I get the same error. What do I miss? See also `The optional sense string defines the sense of the quadratic constrint. Allowed values are '<', '=' or '>'. If not present, the default sense is '<'. It is stored in model$quadcon[[i]]$sense. ` (Without the sense argument, my code runs through...)

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is that, in general, a quadratic equality is not convex, and most solvers only work for convex problems (plus integer constraints). A product of two binary variables is easy to linearise (it's the equivalent of a logical AND), that of one binary variable and one continuous variable is easy too; the rest is not so easy.

Since Gurobi 9, you can solve nonconvex bilinear problems, in particular those having quadratic equality constraints. [You just have to add the right parameter](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041016611-What-does-Objective-Q-not-PSD-or-Quadratic-equality-constraints-mean-). With Gurobi.jl, if `m` is your JuMP model, you can do this:

```
set_optimizer_attribute(m, "NonConvex", 2)
```