# Can Gurobi (>= 8.1) solve ILP with quadratic equality constraint within R-interface?

Tags: r, gurobi

From the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42598827/5784831) 3 years ago
it seems, this is not possible. The Gurobi documentation is not clear ro me:

[the model argument](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/the_model_argument.html) state

> **quadcon (optional)**
>   ...
>   The optional sense string defines the sense of
>   the quadratic constrint. Allowed values are `<`, `=` or `>`. If not
>   present,  the default sense is `<`. It is stored in
>   `model$quadcon[[i]]$sense`.

[constraints](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/constraints.html) state

> **Quadratic Constraints**
>   ...
>   Quadratic equality constraints are always
>   non-convex; they will give a `GRB_ERROR_QCP_EQUALITY_CONSTRAINT` 
>   error with default settings.
>   [...] If you set the `NonConvex` parameter to 2, however, then Gurobi will  accept arbitrary quadratic
>   constraints and attempt to solve the resulting model.

But `NonConvex` throws an `Error 10007: Unknown parameter: 'NonConvex'` in R.
Any help is appreciated, a reproducible example can be found below:

```
library(Matrix)
model <- list(
  modelsense = "min", 
  Q = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L)), 
  A = structure(c(36, 0, 24, 0, -23, 0, -49, 1), .Dim = c(2L, 4L)), 
  rhs = c(0, 1), 
  sense = c("=", ">="), 
  vtype = "I", 
  quadcon = list(list(Qc = new("dgTMatrix", i = 0:3, j = 0:3, 
                              Dim = c(4L, 4L), 
                              Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL), 
                              x = c(1, 1, 1, -2), 
                              factors = list()),
                     # sense = "<=", # works fine
                     sense = ">=", # Error 10020: Q matrix is not positive semi-definite (PSD)
                     sense = "=", # Error 10021: Quadratic equality constraints
                     rhs = 0)))

params <- list(OutputFlag = 0)
result <- gurobi::gurobi(model, params)
print(result$x)
```

Comment: Can you verify that you are running Gurobi 9.0? The "unknown parameter" error hints at an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mattmilten already said in the comments, it's necessary to upgrade to version 9.0. Then it should work with

```
params <- list(OutputFlag = 0, NonConvex = 2)
```